# Why don't they just issue search warrants for Steve Bannon's documents?

Tags: united-states, subpoena, warrant

One of the contempt charges Bannon face is for not handing over documents to the Jan 6th committee.  Why can't they just issue search warrants for every location remotely-associated with Bannon and get them themselves?  Why do they need Bannon to turn them over?

Comment: Maybe they're encrypted, stored on password-protected devices, or stored on the cloud associated with Bannon's accounts? In such cases it is much easier to ask Bannon to turn them over than to attempt to gain access to devices (although law enforcement may have some tools for decrypting devices, or be able to require Google, Apple, etc, to turn over data, if they know what they are looking for).

Comment: Ignoring any legal impediment to doing so, I think you are greatly underestimating just how many locations could be considered "remotely associated" with Bannon, and how much time and money it would take to search them.

Answer (score 18):

First, let's be clear about who "they" is.  Neither Congress nor the Department of Justice has the power to issue search warrants by themselves.  Search warrants are issued by judges, upon a showing of probable cause by the prosecution.

In particular, search warrants can only be issued in *criminal* investigations.  [Federal Rules of Criminal Procedure, Rule 41c](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcrmp/rule_41):

> (c) Persons or Property Subject to Search or Seizure. A warrant may be issued for any of the following:
>
> (1) evidence of a crime;
>
> (2) contraband, fruits of crime, or other items illegally possessed;
>
> (3) property designed for use, intended for use, or used in committing a crime; or
>
> (4) a person to be arrested or a person who is unlawfully restrained.

I don't think Bannon's documents fit any of those criteria at this time.  The Congressional investigation is not a criminal investigation, and I'm not aware that it's currently being alleged that the documents contain evidence of a crime.

Bannon himself is charged with a crime - contempt of Congress - but the actual content of the documents isn't relevant evidence in that case.  As I understand it, the prosecution only has to prove that the subpoena was properly issued, and that Bannon failed to respond to it, which latter I don't think is disputed.  What is actually in those documents, or indeed whether they even exist, is immaterial to his guilt or innocence on that charge.

Comment: Also note that even if Bannon is convicted and fined/sent to prison for failing to respond to the subpoena, he *still* doesn't have to hand over any documents.  They will still need to open a criminal investigation and get a warrant if they want to force that.

Comment: I believe that the prosecution in the contempt case also has to prove that Bannon was obliged to respond to the subpoena by providing the requested documents.  As far as I can determine, this is the central point of contention in the case.  It's not clear to me how much it is a question of law *vs* a question of fact.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Well, [according to the indictment](https://www.justice.gov/opa/press-release/file/1447811/download), the subpoena ordered him to *either* provide the documents, *or* to provide a detailed log of which documents were being withheld and why.  Allegedly he didn't do either of those; he just sent a blanket claim of executive privilege.  But right, they do have to show that the subpoena was binding and that he was obliged to comply with it; I thought of that as part of "properly issued".

Comment: (c)(1), (c)(2), and (c)(3) all seem to apply. It also isn't obvious that the Federal Rules of Criminal Procedure are the exclusive means by which a search warrant remedy is available.

Comment: Also of note, "Contempt of Congress" is almost entirely a political charge, and rarely results in actual jail time or fines. Make no mistake, regardless of what you think of the previous administration, this current congressional endeavor is political and doesn't really care if criminal evidence is found or not - that's not the point of the show.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: Indeed, Congress's investigative powers are meant to uphold the balance of powers between the three branches: they can demand government documents from the executive and judicial branches all day long, but as soon as they demand them from private citizens they're violating the Fourth Amendment.  If the Justice Department makes a choice to investigate or not which Congress doesn't like, they can punish said Justice Department officials via impeachment (in theory, but they don't even when said officials are engaged in crimes).

Comment: As someone unfamiliar with details of Bannon's actions in response to this subpoena specifically, why didn't/wouldn't Bannon simply say "these documents don't exist" and avoid being in contempt of Congress? Is there evidence what is being requested does exist?

Comment: @TCooper Probably because if further investigation revealed that the documents *did* in fact exist, and he knew about them, he could then be indicted for perjury, which is potentially an even more serious charge.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Thanks, so would the lack of supplying them and lack of denial (practically, obviously not legally) imply their existence?

Comment: @TCooper I'm not a lawyer, but I imagine a jury might infer that.  It certainly wouldn't look good for him if he testified under oath that they didn't exist and then they were later found to exist, even worse if it turns out they existed but were then destroyed (destruction of evidence is another serious charge), so it's safer for him to not make any such explicit denial.